# How to set background for qml gridview in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

How to set background of `gridview` from QML file.

Comment: Have a look at examples here : http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeexamples.html - These may already have been installed as part of your SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nest the grid view in a Rectangle and make the delegates of the GridView elements transparent:

```
    Rectangle {
      color: "red"
      GridView {
        delegate: Rectangle {
          color: "transparent"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can also play around with the example proposed by xk0der by setting the 'z:' property of the image smaller than that of the delegate. This will make the image appear below the delegates.

Comment: `Rectangle { color: "transparent" }` doesn't make any sense, does it? Why not just `Item {}`? I mean, the only thing Rectangle does is printing a background, which you want to disable... :)

Comment: @leemes actually rectangle with transparent color is better you can set border radius + clip to create round rect for card like uses with a delegate to implement your card control for example

Answer (score 2):

In QML you can compose complex objects by including/nesting widgets/elements within each other.

So for including an image inside a Widget, in your case the `GridView`, just nest an `Image` element, inside `GridView` Element or it's sub elements as required.

```
GridView {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    Image: {
       source: "some-image.png"
    }
}
```

The documentation for `GridView` has similar and better examples - http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-gridview.html#example-usage

Also look out for the `anchors` attribute, which will help you position the image in the parent Element, or otherwise.

Documentation for `Image` element is available here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qml-image.html

Comment: Thanks for your post ,but nesting image inside gridview hides gridview elements , i want to set image as a background of the gridview.

Comment: I can nest gridview inside the rectangle and set the image inside rectangle that way , the i can set the background image , but i dont know how to make gridview background transparent. I appreciate your help.